# Swipe left or right in listview to show the bottom listitems in top in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, listview, cordova

[image]

I google for this one but i didn't get any reference so i posted here. In my phonegap application i have created a listview like above. In that listview i am able to swipe left or right to do delete and some other actions. But i need when `swipe right` i need to `display the remaining listitems at the top` when `swipe left` the the `previously visible listitems should be visible`.

example  I have `100 listitems` now myscreen `shows first 10 items` when i `swipe left` in listview then it shows `next ten items` that is 11-20 items then i `swipe right` it comes `reverse` like `11-20 items` to `1-10 items` if you have any idea suggest.

.....Thank you.